# Want to return different value from same reducer in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import {FETCH_OBSERVATION} from '../actions/index';
import {DELETE_OBSERVATION} from '../actions/index';

export default function(state={all:[],count:null},action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_OBSERVATION:
    console.log("data for fetch observationCount",action.payload.data.model.observationInstanceList);

     return{
       all:state.all.concat(action.payload.data.model.observationInstanceList),
       count:action.payload.data.model.observationCount
     }
    case DELETE_OBSERVATION:
    return state.all=[];
    default:
    return state

  }
  return state;
}
```

I am fetching data from the API using action creator define in action/index file.
Can Anybody told me why state.all.concat is not defined ?

the error look something like this

```
Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at ./src/reducers/reducer_observation.js.__webpack_exports__.a (reducer_observation.js:10)
at combination (combineReducers.js:120)
at dispatch (createStore.js:165)
at redux-logger.js:1
at index.js:28
at dispatch (applyMiddleware.js:35)
at action.payload.then._extends.payload (index.js:25)
at <anonymous>
```

My Combine Reducer look like this

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SpeciesChartReducer from './reducer_chart_data';
import ObservationReducer from './reducer_observation';
import TaxonReducer from './reducer_taxon_list';
import  UserGroupNames from './reducer_fetch_userGroup';
import  UserGroupObservations from './reducer_fetch_groupobservations';
import  HomeTotalCount from './reducer_home_total_count';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  Observation:ObservationReducer,
  ChartData:SpeciesChartReducer,
  treeData:TaxonReducer,
  UserGroupNames:UserGroupNames,
  UserGroupObservations:UserGroupObservations,
  HomeTotalCount:HomeTotalCount
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `console.log thing`? this: `action.payload.data.model.observationInstanceList`?

Comment: With `return state.all=[];` you're mutating the state and also returning a state of different shape. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do. You probably want to return the default state again. Best to extract it to a `const`. E.g.: `const DEFAULT_STATE = {all:[],count:null};` outside the reducer, and inside: `function(state=DEFAULT_STATE,action){` and later: `case DELETE_OBSERVATION: return DEFAULT_STATE;`.

Comment: Actually i am implementing filter on observation page. So once new filter apply i want to delete the displayed observation,  and load new new Observation, that's why  i am deleting the previous after  doing this "state.all:[]".
If u have any idea, the please share considering the above scenario.
The project i am working on is OpenSource u can look the functional website here. 

http://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/list?view=list

The above page is what i want to implement.

Comment: It's not really relevant what you try to achieve at the end, mutating and returning different shapes of state is simple the wrong thing to do. Reference: [Never mutate reducer arguments](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

Comment: *"...that's why i am deleting the previous after doing this "state.all:[]""* But that's the problem. You're 1) deleting it by mutating the state, bad. 2) You're returning a different shape of state (state is now the result of the expression `state.all=[];` which is a plain array), bad. What you want to do, is to return a new state with the correct shape (meaning same properties). And if you do that, you'll realize it looks a lot like your default state. Hence why I recommend extracting it.

Comment: Thanks Dude. 
Thats an open Source project, and i am the alone working on it. 
If u want to contribute, then let me know. 
the github url is https://github.com/strandls/biodiv-ui. 
I am trying to update the previous UI into the new UI using ReactJs.
Please look into the code, and suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so if u want above function to work, then do like this.

```
import {FETCH_OBSERVATION} from '../actions/index';
import {DELETE_OBSERVATION} from '../actions/index';
const DEFAULT_STATE={all:[],count:null}
export default function(state=DEFAULT_STATE,action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_OBSERVATION:
     return{
       all:state.all.concat(action.payload.data.model.observationInstanceList),
       count:action.payload.data.model.observationCount
     }
    case DELETE_OBSERVATION:
    return DEFAULT_STATE;
    default:
    return DEFAULT_STATE

  }
  return DEFAULT_STATE;
}
```

`